# Use cookie to pre-populate the information in desktop app

Tags: php, c++, desktop, populate, auto-populate

I have very specific problem.

I have web based application which set cookie after login. The same login details are used in desktop application which is connected to the web interface.

My idea was is it possible that when the user logins first in web app and it set cookie for him, then he downloads the application, install it on his PC and start it for first time somehow to get the user and password and auto fill the login fields in desktop application, so it won't be necessary to write them second time.

One of the ways is to save the login and password in a plaintext in cookie, which is very risky and then the desktop app gets this cookie from the browser (the app is written in c++).

I really don't have any clear idea at the moment how this could be done, but if there is a way I will be happy to red any of your suggestions.

Comment: You don't have to store the password in plain text, you can encrypt it.  This is less dangerous (though still dangerous).

Answer (score 0):

The main issue I see is actually getting to the cookie. I can't see how you'd do that reliably with all the OSes / OS versions, browsers / browser versions out there. You could maybe include an encrypted resource file in the download containing the credentials. You can put that into the downloaded archive on the server side.

Is downloading without a login really not an option?

**Edit:** including a one-use token in the download, using which the client can fetch the username and password (via SSL, encrypted, somehow safe) looks like a good bet.

Comment: Actually everybody can download the application without login. I mean we could have a case when the user download and install first the application and then login to the web application. In this case we can't auto fill the login fields of desktop app with the login information. But in a case when the user logins first in web app and then start for first time the desktop app, then I have to get the login details somehow ...

Comment: I see. If that's a requirement, then the best solution I can think of is to include something (maybe just a token, not the username/password) in the download bundle.

Comment: Ok, but what about after I get this token? I mean I have a installer which the user runs on his PC. Can you give me an example of your idea so I can see what do you mean exactly? Thanks.

Comment: After you have the token, you query the server with it. If the token hasn't been used yet, then the server returns the username and password in as safe a way as possible. The client then fills in the login form with the data from the response.This assumes that you can give the token to the installed application. If that's not possible, then the idea is shot.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was thinking actually ... is there a way to pass this token to the application ... If yes, then it would be much easier. I mean there is no problem with the token. this is the easy part when the app will communicate with the server. The hard thing is how exactly the desktop app will receive/get this token. User download .exe file which after that runs/install. The thing is that after the installation the application have to find somewhere this token ...

Comment: The token can either be in a separate file or inside the `.exe`. If it's in a separate file, then that will have to be included in an archive with the .exe, slightly altering the installation process (making the user download the token file separately is even less convenient than logging in again). Inserting the token into the `.exe` can be simple or next to impossible depending on how much control you have, and whether you can manipulate the installer (either before or after compilation) via C#. Unfortunately I don't have the experience to take the solution any further.